# Clang C Block : block function definition after call

Tags: c, clang, nested-function

I'm trying to port some GCC nested function to clang. As gcc nested function is not supported in clang, i need to use c-block instead.

But i want to have the block definition after the call to it. (I need this order because code is generated from MACRO and i can not arrange this order)

So in gcc i have this pseudo code :

```
foo(){
  auto void bar (void);
  ...
  bar()
  ...
  void bar(void) {
    ...some stuff
  }
}
```

You i can do this in C-block clang function ?

This code works fine

```
int main() {
  void (^hello)(void);

  hello = ^(void){
    printf("Hello, block!\n");
  };

  hello();
  return 0;
}
```

But the following code

```
int main() {
  void (^hello)(void);

  hello();

  hello = ^(void){
    printf("Hello, block!\n");
  };

  return 0;
}
```

failed with an segfault.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Portable nested functions in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12214867/portable-nested-functions-in-c) or [Rewrite GCC cleanup macro with nested function for Clang?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959440/rewrite-gcc-cleanup-macro-with-nested-function-for-clang)

Answer (score 0):

In your second example, `hello` has not been defined before you call it, so it is an undefined symbol. You have to tell the compiler *what* something is before you can use it.

In your pseudocode, a function prototype preceeds everything, which gets around the error by telling the compiler "this will be defined later on."